# mapping Excel file who have more columns then aData Table

Tags: c#, excel, datatable

I have data stored in an exel file,i access to the file using  OleDbConnection ,and i try to fill up a Data Table .
My probleme is that i try to map the exel file who have more columns then the  Data Table ,i try to do it this way,and i use the code below[image] :
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an Example:

```
var connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source={0}; Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1;\"", source);
var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", connectionString);
var ds = new DataSet();

adapter.Fill(ds, "Sheet1");
_ = ds.Tables["Sheet1"];
```

- `source` is the path of the File
- Remember to change the Name of the Sheet from the Select if its different
- In the connectionString i put `HDR=No` because i needed a copy of the excel without 
  Headers. I see that you have Headers so put Yes or just remove that part.
- I use DataSet and every Sheet is a DataTable into the DataSet. When you need to use Sheets just call them as `ds.Tables[0]` or create a `DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0]`
- With this OleDB code u can open only .xls

Comment: Andreito ,thanks ,my problem is that in my excel File i have  5 column and in my Data Table i want to have only three like my image represantation .

Answer (score 0):

When you using OleDbConnection to read excel file, it's fill data to a datatable with column name is first row in excel file. You can use column name to mapping.